# Finding if float is between two floats in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, lookup

I'm trying to find a more elegant way of looking up a number in a table.

Example:
I have the value 13 for column A and 9.8 for column B.
the biggest row that 13 is larger than is row 4 so I look into row 4 column B and compare that number to my column B number. Depending on if my column B number was bigger or smaller than row 4 column B I would do something.

[image: lookupTable]

This is what I have so far but it seems messy. Is there a way I could store all the floats in a list or dictionary to make this look better? I can't seem to find a way to look if a float is between another float other than just verbosely comparing each one.

```
table = []
someOtherFloat = 13.0
someFloat = 9.8


if someOtherFloat >= 21.2:
    table.insert(2, 25.4)
    if someFloat >= 25.4:
        print 'something'
    else:
        print 'something'
elif 18.8 <= someOtherFloat < 21.2:
    if someFloat >= 21.9:
        print 'something'
    else:
        print 'something else'
    table.insert(2, 21.9)
elif 14.2 <= someOtherFloat < 18.8:
    if someFloat >= 14.7:
        print 'something'
    else:
        print 'something else'
    table.insert(2, 14.7)
elif 9.0 <= someOtherFloat < 14.2:
    if someFloat >= 10.4:
        print 'something'
    else:
        print 'I should get printed by this code' # <--------------
    table.insert(2, 10.4)
elif 5.7 <= someOtherFloat < 9.0:
    if someFloat >= 7.0:
        print 'something'
    else:
        print 'something else'
    table.insert(2, 7.0)
elif 2.9 <= someOtherFloat < 5.7:
    if someFloat >= 5.0:
        print 'something'
    else:
        print 'something else'
    table.insert(2, 5.0)
elif 0.6 <= someOtherFloat < 2.9:
    if someFloat >= 3.5:
        print 'something'
    else:
        print 'something else'
    table.insert(2, 3.5)
else:    
    if someFloat >= 2.3:
        print 'something'
    else:
        print 'something else'
    table.insert(2, 2.3)
```

I've tried doing the following but it doesn't work.

```
checkme = [1.0, 2.3, 3.4]
checkme2 = ['hi', 'bye', 'hello']
def findBucket(aFloat):
    for key in checkme:
        if aFloat < key:
            print checkme2[key]
            return
    print final
    return

findBucket(3.0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in findBucket
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not float
```

The following code seems to work the best

```
column_a = [21.2, 18.8, 14.2, 9.0, 5.7, 2.9, 0.6, -1.6]
column_b = [25.4, 21.9, 14.7, 10.4, 7.0, 5.0, 3.5, 2.3]


def findBucket(aFloat):
    i = 0
    while i < len(column_a):
        if aFloat > column_a[i]:
            print column_b[i]
            return
        i += 1
    return


findBucket(18.9)
21.9
findBucket(13.2)
10.4
findBucket(2.7)
3.5
```

Comment: You have a pattern. Create a function that parameterizes the three floats.

Comment: More information is needed: what if all numbers in column A are larger (than 13), or if there are more than one rows that fit the requirement.

Comment: I am trying to find the largest number in column A that is less than my 'column A' number, if no numbers fit that criteria I handle it elsewhere in the code. I'm only comparing one row (the row with the biggest column A number) so I don't need to worry about comparing to more than one number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could iterate over a dictionary mapping actions to the lower/upper bound, doing comparisons against that dictionary:

```
# I used strings here which I print in the function, but you could very well
# assign methods as values.
checkme = {1.0:"hi!",2.3:"bye",3.4:"hello!"}
final = "goodbye"
def findBucket(aFloat):
    for key in checkme.keys():
        if aFloat < key:
            print checkme[key]
            return
    # getting to this point means aFloat was greater than the last key
    print final
    return
```

Alternative solution, with two lists:

```
checkme = [1.0, 2.3, 3.4] 
checkme2 = ['hi', 'bye', 'hello', 'finalanswer'] 
def findBucket(aFloat): 
    i = 0
    while i < len(checkme): 
        if aFloat < checkme[i]: 
            print checkme2[i]
            return 
        i += 1
    print checkme2[-1] #negative indexing starts from the end of the list in python
    return
```

Comment: Note: this isn't the greatest style, as dictionaries don't automatically sort their keys. You could alternatively store two adjacent lists with corresponding values. This was just slightly easier to write up :)

Comment: What do you mean by two adjacent lists?

Comment: you are using [key] as the index here. In this case, use a while loop and an int to iterate through it. I'll add a separate solution to my answer shortly.

Comment: In your edited question, your code has the problem of calling a string index on a list. Remember, lists can only be accessed with integer values.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

def findBucket(aFloat):
    df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [21.2,18.8,14.2,9,5.7,2.9,0.6,-1.6], 
                       'B': [25.4,21.9,14.7,10.4,7,5,3.5,2.3]})     
    return(df.B.iloc[df.A.apply(lambda x: x if aFloat - x > 0 else 0).idxmax()])
```

Explanation:

- Populate a data frame with values as defined by OP.
- Calculate (aFloat - <entries in column A>); if any happens to be negative, substitute with zero. This helps in finding the largest value in column A that is less than aFloat.
- Find the index idx where the largest value thus calculated resides in column A
- Find the value in the column B, index idx and return it.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.